# Google Play Consoles - Check rollout percentage of a release in production

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

How to check and eventually update the percentage of rollout for an application in production ?

In the past I have been able to change the deployment percentage of an application in production using this [documentation](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6346149?sjid=6396467614492058697-EU#increase&zippy=%2Cincrease-your-staged-rollout-percentage), but I no longer see the *Manage rollout* button for the version of the application in production.

Has anything changed? I can't find any official documentation that helps me determine the rollout percentage of a release and eventually change it.

Comment: The documentation still details the process correctly as far as i can see. I have a manage rollout option.